# 301-redirect without subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to perform a 301-redirect from a homepage, but without redirecting my subdomains.

**Example:**

```
http://info.org => http://newpage.org
http://www.info.org => http://newpage.org
http://subdomain.info.org => http://subdomain.info.org
```

**My current htaccess already includes a 301-redirect from www to non-www:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.info.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://info.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**My question:**

How can I redirect my Page with a 301-redirect as described in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?info\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^test(/.*)?$ http://newpage.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

This will redirect:

```
http://info.org => http://newpage.org
http://www.info.org => http://newpage.org
```

But `http://info.org/test` OR `http://subdomain.info.org` will remain unaffected.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast answer. One question though: What would I need to change that it would affect all subdomains as well?

Comment: To affect all subdomains as well you can use: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)info\.org$ [NC]` condition.

Comment: Once I have tested it successfully I will accept your answer

Comment: Can I exclude a specific url? Like all files in a specific folder: http://info.org/test/* get no redirect?